# How to prevent Django admin from adding changelist filters twice to the URL with active 301 redirect to https?

Tags: django, redirect, nginx, https, django-admin-filters

Django 1.8.3 on nginx setup that redirects admin pages to HTTPS:

```
upstream project_pass {
    server 127.1.1.1:0000;
}

server {
    listen          443;
    server_name     subdomain.domain.ext;

    ssl on;

    ...

    location / {
            uwsgi_pass      project_pass;
            include         uwsgi_params;
    }
}

server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     subdomain.domain.ext;

    location / {
            rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri permanent;
    }
}
```

After activating any filter on the object list page it is stored in the `_changelist_filters` `GET` variable and added to the form `action` on object edit page. But at least on Firefox the form is at first submitted to HTTP somehow, gets redirected to the HTTPS and somewhere in the process `GET` filters are set two times, like this:

```
https://domain.ext/admin/project/model/?status__exact=new?status__exact=new
```

I cannot nor find any similar bugs that are already created neither create one on the Django Trac (please do it if you can confirm the problem).

What can I do to prevent these double filters (they make admin usage quite uncomfortable) and still have all /admin requests redirected to HTTPS?

P.S. Running server with `runserver` is not affected by this problem, obviously.

Comment: share your complete server config, only `rewrite` line is not sufficient for solving this issue.

Comment: I think sharing the *whole* config is a security threat. I'll expand just the redirect part, I think that will be enough.

Comment: yes, expand it. Because issue isn't being caused by this line for sure.

Comment: Added almost all related lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the http headers correctly (most importantly X-Forwarded-Proto), otherwise django doesn't know that the first request is an https request, and assumes it's http, so all the links it creates are http links.

```
location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        uwsgi_pass      project_pass;
        include         uwsgi_params;
}
```

This would prevent the http links. Also, your rewrite command should have a question mark at the end, so nginx won't add the GET arguments twice:

```
location / {
        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

You might want to consider using the simpler [return](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return) directive.

```
location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, headers didn't work, but both question mark and `return` worked.

Comment: Keep in mind that if the django links send you back to http you're vulnerable to ssl strip attacks.

Comment: I've added the `HSTS` header and even after that it looks like the `GET` request is sent unsecure first: http://i.imgur.com/T0aHi0a.png